# Accessing FTP through netsuite

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I want to schedule a script on NetSuite to upload and download a txt file from an FTP location. I am able to create a file and store it in a file cabinet but that is as far as I can go.

I am a bit new and don't know if at all is it possible to have FTP scheduled from NetSuite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no FTP access to NetSuite.

You can work around that limitation with a scheduled script or web services however.

Here is a previous post with example code on how to start a scheduled script: [How to upload a file to Netsuite File Cabinet Automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289397/how-to-upload-a-file-to-netsuite-file-cabinet-automatically)

> 1. Place your CSV file into a location that is publicly visible(obviously, this only works if it's not sensitive information! PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE don't do this if you don't want the whole world to see it!)
> 2. Create a scheduled script in NetSuite. Set the deployment to run daily, at whatever time you deem best
> 3. In your scheduled script, use nlapiRequestUrl (NS help doc) to get the file from wherever you placed it (Note that there is a 5mb size limitation!)
> 4. Use nlapiCreateFile (NS help doc) to create a file
> 5. Use nlapiSubmitFile (NS help doc) to submit it to the file cabinet
>      Sample code:
>
>    var response = nlapiRequestURL('http://yourserver.yourcompany.com/somecsvfile.csv');
>      var csvDataInBase64 = response.getBody();
>      var file = nlapiCreateFile('mycsv.csv', 'CSV', csvDataInBase64);
>      nlapiSubmitFile(file);
>
> There is no error checking or anything in that sample, but it should get you started.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no native mechanism for the FTP protocol in JavaScript or NS. You will need to instead use the HTTP protocol as @xengravity indicated.

Answer (score 2):

In SuiteScript 2.0 you can upload/download to SFTP locations using the N/sftp module. Here is a snippet of code I have used for a customer.

```
            var csvfile = file.create({
                'name': 'transactions.csv',
                'fileType': file.Type.CSV,
                'contents': filecontents
            });

            var conn = sftp.createConnection({
                'username': username,
                'passwordGuid': passwordGuid,
                'url': url,
                'directory': directory,
                'hostKey': hostkey
            });

            conn.upload({
                'file': csvfile,
                'replaceExisting': true
            });
```